# $A^2$ as the zero matrix why cannot have non-zero eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $A^2$ is the zero matrix. Show that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and explain why $A$ can have no other eigenvalues.

---

This is a question that puzzles me a lot. Could anyone please help me figure out why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then for some vector $x\neq 0$ we have $Ax = \lambda x$, and $A^2 x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda Ax = \lambda^2 x$. But $A^2=0$, so $0\cdot x=A^2x=\lambda^2x \Rightarrow \lambda^2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=0$. This shows that $0$ is the only possible eigenvalue of $A$.

Now, $A^2=0$ can happen only if $A$ is not invertible, which is the same as saying that it has a nontrivial kernel. Thus, there exists $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax=0=0\cdot x$. This $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @lhf I corrected the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

suppose $e$ is an eingenvector for a non zero eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
$A^2(e)=A(\lambda e)=\lambda A(e)=\lambda^2e$, which is non zero. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Yeah, that was easy for me: the first column of A times A equals to a zero column, so 0 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very straightforward and powerful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.

Therefore, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^2=0$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2=0$ and so $\lambda^2=0$.